# Opencart extension not creating files

Tags: opencart, ocmod

I have a custom Opencart shipping extension. It has `upload/` and `install.xml`. When I upload `extension.ocmod.zip` through extension installer, it completes installation. But the extension is not visible under `Extensions > Shipping`.

I checked the code and none of the files from the extension is present under `upload/admin/controller/extension/shipping`.

I have refreshed modifications and cache from the dashboard.

Comment: Have you enabled Access Permissions and Modify permissions of you new extension in Admin dashboard System/Users/User group for   administrator?

Comment: My extension doesn't show under System/Users/User Groups/ Administrator

Comment: so seems you have made some errors in your code. If your code properly writed extension should appear. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go through my code again

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the OC version you're using, my guess is that your path structure should be:

- install.xml
- upload/admin/view/extension/shipping/*
- upload/admin/model/extension/shipping/*
- upload/admin/controller/extension/shipping/*
- upload/admin/language/en-gb/extension/shipping/*
- upload/catalog/view/theme/default/extension/shipping/*
- upload/catalog/model/extension/shipping/*
- upload/catalog/controller/extension/shipping/*
- upload/catalog/language/en-gb/extension/shipping/*

Comment: not correct. He is creating shipping module, so it is little bit different. Should be not `upload/admin/catalog/view/extension/module/*` but `upload/admin/catalog/view/extension/shipping/*` and so on. Of course it depends which version of the OC. There can be little bit different file structure. But main your suggestion are correct to understand which files and structure of the files are used.

Comment: Thanks @K.B. I've incorporated your feedback

Comment: Should it be admin/catalog/controller/extension/shipping or admin/controller/extension/shipping ?

Comment: @user13345 it's probably admin/controller/extension/shipping - sorry for the inaccuracy. I included the catalog folder out of habit!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your file `extension.ocmod.zip` contains:

the `upload` folder and `install.xml` file **directly**

and there is not another **subdirectory** contains them

Comment: That is how it is